# Do Windows users experience "Java App can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer" or is it just for Macs?

Tags: java

Full question is in the title.

Comment: Yes, Octopus, because the objective of this entire site is "to get an answer relevant to the subject at hand". The subject is programming/computing in this area. As with any site, the objective remains intact and should be aimed for. 

Saying that you're smug isn't an insult, it's a condition you find yourself in. Therefore, there is no harm in not catering to your emotions and instead stating a simple truth.

Comment: When running Java Applications on browser or from desktop. It does not matter.

Comment: It matters a lot in the Windows world. (Side note: In a browser, they're called *applets*, not applications.)

Comment: Thank you! I know it's an applet, but generally, it's still an application.
Application noun 5 (also application program )Computinga program or piece of software designed and written to fulfill a particular purpose of the user. May I confirm that you do receive those problems in Windows and not just Mac? Is the resolution in locating Security and allowing the application to run?

Comment: And yet, **it matters to be specific** when asking for help.

Comment: The error is received by Macs with either an Applet or Application, so whether it is an Applet or Application does not matter. Specificity is not required here, just an answer if Windows users receive a problem when trying to run a Java [General word: ] application regarding it not being from an unidentified developer.

Comment: *"...so whether it is an Applet or Application does not matter"* Of course it does. It *may* not on Macs (although I suspect you're just plain wrong there), but it certainly does everywhere else -- Windows, non-Mac \*nix, ...

Comment: Okay, the same error was received when I ran an applet on my webpage as the error that was received when I made it downloadable to desktop. You're right, I should have specified "If it's possible to receive an error...".

Answer (score 1):

For applets, it depends on the browser vendor. Some will run unsigned applets, others will not, others will with just a warning message. Some won't even run signed applets (Chrome on Linux discontinued support for NPAPI plugins, including the Java plugin, months ago and Chrome on Windows will do so later this year if they stick to their plan. There is no PPAPI equivalent, nor is it likely there even can be.)

For *applications*, no, you can run any Java class you like on Windows without a warning.